# WPF: MediaElement to play online videos

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, media-player

I am creating a WPF media player using MediaElement class in WPF. Here i can play the local videos (Available in my PC) but i cannot play an online video. Can anybody knows what i have to do for this?

Please help me anybody.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you can totally do that. However, you may running into issues with the type of video you're trying to play (file type), an authentication issue with the site you're trying to stream videos from (i.e. you need to be logged in), or the URL is malformed/incorrect. One way to test that is to hook up the `MediaFailed` event handler and pop up a message whenever that's raised so you can get some insight into what's going on.

I was able to wire this up in a few minutes. The H.264 videos worked fine for me.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MyMediaElement.MediaFailed += MyMediaElement_MediaFailed;
    MyMediaElement.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Play;
    MyMediaElement.Source = 
        new Uri(@"http://somesite/somevideo.mp4", UriKind.Absolute);
}

void MyMediaElement_MediaFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.ErrorException.Message);
}
```

Comment: Also: `MediaElement` won't work with `https` because it can't authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

As WPF mediaelement internally uses windows media player. If you alter the buffer settings of media player from default buffer setting to custom. Open windows media player  Tools  Options  Performance.  As highlighted in the image below.

When you choose “Buffer” option and set “Seconds of content” to 2. The following registry values will be added under media player.
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MediaPlayer\Preferences
 UseDefaultBufferTime=0
 CustomBufferTime=2000

You can use dotnet registry class to make changes.
Refer this link:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1b4b8fb9-ff8f-4861-8e99-4a7a4fc75596/setting-windows-media-player-properties-in-wpf?forum=wpf#ac879a7f-37bc-4ccc-854d-ab6e047086e5